# How to solve it. Texteditor in a textarea then it makes the page load slow?

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, text-editor

I use ckeditor plugin.

I created a page for data. Each page will have a textarea field with 11 fields per page.
and textarea need to be fixed use ckeditor plugin the page.

How can I solve these problems. Or is there another way to introduce it.

PS. This is problem. I have all 7 pages, and textarea field with 11 fields per page.
total 77 times on load ckeditor. solving the problem, 
I use ajax to assist in loading. To each page, load the ckeditor comes just 11 times, 
but it slow.
I wanted to ask. There are possible solutions. Or the other way I would recommend it.

Thanks.

Comment: why would you need 77 editors on one page? couldn't you just load one and add a button to load another one if needed?

Comment: I have a need to use a textarea so that each will have different functions. And effect change in an instant. Is able to display. Screen simulation of the system. In the beginning, I tried using the clone function. But it does not meet the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the ckeditor in a page, and include it on any page.

```
include('editor.php');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Having 77 input boxes (textarea or ckeditbox) will confuse the user of your site.

Is it not better to group related sets and put them in tabs? http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Not sure what's slow, is it the loading of the script because I can't find anything in the documentation about loading script on every ckedit box: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed

If loading is slow because all 77 boxes get their content through ajax calls then consider using tab or split them up in several pages.

Comment: my system is now a 7 tab and click on the tab. Will be called the page file to ajax. Available to display.

I tried a number of ways. function clones. and change texteditor , but it does not help anything.

Comment: What takes the longest time? Is  it initializing the ckeditor or loading the content of the text?

Comment: initializing the ckeditor about 30 seconds
and loading the content of the text about 20 seconds

Comment: Loading text content is a anynchronyous xmlhttp request I assume so that should not hang up other scripts. Maybe you can initialise the ckeditor in a timeout (setTimeout(function(){doinit.call(null,"box1");},100);) where "box1" is the first box, you'll loop through all 7 boxes like that.